# Castle Validators how to Validate Is Lesser/Greater Than Or Equal

Tags: castle-validators

I see the ValidateIsLesser and ValidateIsGreater attributes. But what if I want to do a ValidateIsLesserOrEqual and/or ValidateIsGreaterOrEqual. Do I just need to write these custom attributes or is there pre-built capabilities for this that I am having a hard time finding?

```
[ValidateNonEmpty]
[ValidateDate]
[ValidateIsLesser(IsLesserValidationType.Date, "EndDate", "Start Date must be before End Date.")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

[ValidateNonEmpty]
[ValidateDate]
[ValidateIsGreater(IsGreaterValidationType.Date, "StartDate", "End Date must be after the Start Date.")]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **ValidateSelf** attribute and supply your own validation for the OrEqual comparisons:

```
[ValidateNonEmpty]
[ValidateDate]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

[ValidateNonEmpty]
[ValidateDate]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

[ValidateSelf]
public void ValidateDate(ErrorSummary errors)
{
    if (StartDate >= EndDate)
        errors.RegisterErrorMessage("StartDate", "Start date must be earlier than end date.");
}
```

Comment: awesome idea. this looks like a useful technique for many other situations!